# Brute Force Longest Common Subsequence

Tags: java, algorithm

I have come up with a brute force algorithm for finding the longest common subsequence between two given strings. It looks like it has time complexity of O(n^3). It passes all test cases I have but I'm still not sure if it will pass all test cases or not..... please let me know this is right brute force algorithm?

```
public String lcs(String s1, String s2) {
    int s2Start = 0;
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder("");
    StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder("");

    for(int s1Start = 0; s1Start < s1.length(); s1Start++) {
        s2Start = 0; // reset
        if(temp.length() > result.length()) {
            result = temp;
        }
        temp = new StringBuilder(""); // reset

        for(int i = s1Start; i < s1.length(); i++) {
            char s1Char = s1.charAt(i);

            for(int j = s2Start; j < s2.length(); j++) {
                char s2Char = s2.charAt(j);
                if(s1Char == s2Char) {
                    temp.append(Character.toString(s1Char));
                    s2Start = j + 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if(temp.length() > result.length())
        result = temp;
    return result.toString();
}
```

if above code is not right, I want brute force algorithm to return longest common subsequence string,, how can i acheive this ???

Comment: Do you want to specifically solve it using brute force?

Comment: @NikosTzianas.... yes I want brute algorithm(recursive/iterative) to return longest common subsequence string..... but i found brute force algo which returns length only not string .... is it possible someway ??

Comment: @ManpreetSingh right brute force approach is exponential in running time.

Answer (score 2):

No. This is not a right brute force algorithm to solve LCS problem. 
See this case -

`AKBLC`
`AMBNCK`

Answer of LCS of these two strings should be 3.
But in your algorithm it will calculate 2 (AK).

Comment: how can i make brute algorithm & return the longest common subsequence string ...any ideas ??

Comment: By brute force if you mean greedy algorithm, then that will not work on LCS problem. Here dynamic programming is must. Search google for Dynamic programming to learn.